# Is there a way to have a common time users cannot modify even if they change time in settings

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin, time, utc

I'm working an an app that's Puts and Gets data to Firebase, based on Date, and Time my problem now is that users can modify it in settings and either get future data or old data I've tried using the dateTime.now however that can be modified I've also tried datetime.utcnow but it can also be modified. So my question is is there away I can work this out so users cannot modify time or even if they do the app time isn't affected.?

Sample of code stored to Firebase.

```
        await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
            .Instance
            .Collection(DataPaths.NewsFeed)
            .Document(guid)
            .SetAsync(new {
            ID = ticks + id,
            ProfileImage = prefrences.profileImage,
            UserName = usernames,
            Title = title,
            Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
            Time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss"),
            Details = details,
            OrderTime = orderTime
        });
```

Another Sample of Something I was Attempting.

```
 //All 3 Needs sorting/fixing utc vs local/GMT time
 //DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;      
 //var act = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
 //Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", act.ToString(), "OK");
```

Comment: Doesn't the DB keep its own time?

Comment: Take the time from your Backend.

Comment: Use an NTP Client (https://github.com/nothingmn/robchartier-classlibrary/blob/master/robchartier-classlibrary/Network/NTPClient.cs)

Comment: can you please explain to me how to go about it.?

Comment: Ok thanks will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, that you should get the current time from an API rather than from the device.
The way to do it, is to set `Date` & `Time` to a value gotten from an API.

So I personally like this `http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now`; copy this into your code where you would like to set your date & time, and you should be all fine.
You can edit the API URL to match your time zone; lets say you want Central Standard time, then this would be your API URL `http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/cst/now`.

Feel free to search for other APIs using Google.

**Now**, how do you set your variable to an API result value? ~ Like this:

```
var url = "http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/cst/now";
var client = new HttpClient();

var currentDateTime = client.Get(url);

await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
        .Instance
        .Collection(DataPaths.NewsFeed)
        .Document(guid)
        .SetAsync(new {
        ID = ticks + id,
        ProfileImage = prefrences.profileImage,
        UserName = usernames,
        Title = title,

        Date = currentDateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
        Time = currentDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"),

        Details = details,
        OrderTime = orderTime
    });
```